# How to Improve Panning and Zooming with huge amount of component drawn in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, zooming, panel, pan

Lately I have being learning and experimenting with drawing, zooming and Panning with Winforms Panel.

I have a panel with double buffering where I draw a lot of shapes, when I pan the shapes it still flickers, I want to improve it, one Idea it came into my mind is converting all this shape to one bmp image so I don't need to redraw all the component, I'm not sure if this is the best idea or anyone can help me with better approach.  Here is a snipe it of the code

```
public PanelViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        zoom = zoomTrackPad.Value / 10f;
    }

    public CircuitData ResistorData { get; set; }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.TranslateTransform(imgx, imgy);
        g.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom);
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
        foreach (CircuitData.ResistorRow resistorRow in ResistorData.Resistor)
        {
            RectangleF rec = new RectangleF((float)(resistorRow.CenterX  - resistorRow.Length/ 2), (float)(resistorRow.CenterY - resistorRow.Width/ 2), (float)resistorRow.Length, (float)resistorRow.Width);
            float orientation = 360 - (float)resistorRow.Orientation;
            PointF center = new PointF((float)resistorRow.CenterX, (float)resistorRow.CenterY);
            PointF[] points = CreatePolygon(rec, center, orientation);
            if (!Double.IsNaN(resistorRow.HiX) && !Double.IsNaN(resistorRow.HiY))
            {
                g.FillEllipse(myBrush, (float)resistorRow.HiX  - 2 , (float)resistorRow.HiY - 2, 4, 4);
                g.DrawLine(p, new PointF((float)resistorRow.HiX , (float)resistorRow.HiY ), center);
            }
            g.FillPolygon(myBrush, points);
        }
    }

    private PointF[] CreatePolygon(RectangleF rec, PointF center, float orientation)
    {
        PointF TL = new PointF(rec.Left, rec.Top);
        PointF TR = new PointF(rec.Right, rec.Top);
        PointF BL = new PointF(rec.Left, rec.Bottom);
        PointF BR = new PointF(rec.Right, rec.Bottom);
        PointF[] points = new PointF[] { BL, TL, TR, BR, BL };
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix matrix = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix();
        matrix.RotateAt(orientation, center);
        matrix.TransformPoints(points);
        return points;
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        zoom = zoomTrackPad.Value / 10f;
        Viewer.Invalidate();
    }



    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

        if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mouseDown = mouse.Location;
            startx = imgx;
            starty = imgy;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

            if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Point mousePosNow = mouse.Location;

                int deltaX = mousePosNow.X - mouseDown.X; // the distance the mouse has been moved since mouse was pressed
                int deltaY = mousePosNow.Y - mouseDown.Y;

                imgx = (int)(startx + (deltaX / zoom));  // calculate new offset of image based on the current zoom factor
                imgy = (int)(starty + (deltaY / zoom));

                Viewer.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Caching shapes you draw in a bitmap is a good idea. It clearly beats any of the other suggestions here. Set a limit of maybe a hundred or so (depending on your machine and also the complexity of the shapes - rectangles are cheap, long freehand lines are not) and draw them into a Bitmap which you can then use as the BackgroundImage or Image (if you use a PictureBox which I consider the better choice btw). Using the same data and CreateGraphics(bitmap). Then draw only the shapes after the limit in the Paint event.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing on the Paint event of a panel, a better way (but a bit more complicated) is to create an user control, configre it to be fully user-drawn and override the OnPaint method.

The flickering you see is because the control is being paint on two phases, PaintBackground and Paint, also it's wasting time because it's drawing uneeded content (the original Paint).

To create an user painted control, create a new user control and on the constructor add this:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true); //do not use PaintBackground
SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true); //enable double buffer
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true); //all paint will be done by the user
```

Then override the OnPaint method and do your drawing:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor); //Important!! the control will not be cleared by itself, you must clear it

        //Render your content
    }
```

Also you talk about rendering only the needed areas, that's always a good idea and the OnPaint method is already prepared for this, on the arguments you have a Rectangle named Clipping rectangle with the area which must be redrawn, so instead of clearing all the control just clear the area of this rectangle, intersect it with all the areas of your content (per example in your code you have

```
RectangleF rec = new RectangleF((float)(resistorRow.CenterX  - resistorRow.Length/ 2), (float)(resistorRow.CenterY - resistorRow.Width/ 2), (float)resistorRow.Length, (float)resistorRow.Width);
        float orientation = 360 - (float)resistorRow.Orientation;
```

, that will be the area of the component)  and redraw just the ones intersected.

If you need more info on user drawn controls MSDN has a very good section about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxys6ytf%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Good luck!